# Convert rtf blob to text in MS Sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, blob

I working with database. In this database I have a table with blob field. This field contains rtf text. 
If I'am doing like this:

```
select convert(nvarchar(max),convert(varbinary(max),blob_column)) from table_with_blob
```

it's returns this: せ〰〰〴ㄷⴶ㠰た㠴弰巎楛㵤㠵㜸㔰⁝ﳲ茶￠∠ⰳㄲ㠴.

So my question is how to convert this rtf blob to text using MS Sql 2008?

Comment: Do you have a working solution by now? Having same issue ... and google search only leads to 1. Using CLR , which I cannot, 2. using a script which does not strip all tags...

Comment: is anything having solution for this?

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale In my case I'v created .net dll that converts rtf and call it from Sql stored procedure. Also I'v do that becouse I was needen only text with out rtf tags. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916790/call-dll-function-from-sql-stored-procedure-using-the-current-connection

Comment: @Gleb in my case varbinary RTF already stored in column. now i want to convert to text in SQL. you know any solution ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567600/convert-varbinary-rtf-blob-to-text-in-ms-sql

Answer (score 1):

try with this, it should work

```
select convert(varchar(max),convert(varbinary(max),blob_column)) from table_with_blob
```

take the reference from below script -

```
DECLARE @blob VarBinary(MAX) = CONVERT(VarBinary(MAX), 'test');
-- show the binary representation
SELECT @blob;
-- this doesn't work
SELECT CONVERT(NVarChar(100), @blob);
-- but this does
SELECT CONVERT(VarChar(100), @blob);
```

Comment: Thats doesn't work. Problem is that I have rtf text converted to blob and I need to get just text from it.