# Call dll function from sql stored procedure using the current connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, dll, clr, sqlconnection

Can I call a dll from a stored procedure using the open connection?

I have a dll that gets data from SQL Server and I don't want to open a new connection when I call it from the stored procedure.

Thank you

Here is an exemple

```
public class Class1
{
    public static SqlString GetName(SqlString str)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str.ToString());
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

        string name = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        return name;
    }
}
```

and this is the SQL code

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_TestConnection
(
    @str nvarchar(255)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS EXTERNAL NAME TestConnection.[TestConnection.Class1].GetName
GO

SELECT dbo.fn_TestConnection('SELECT FName FROM Clients WHERE Id = 1' )
```

Answer (score 8):

These instructions are for *Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014*.

**Import the Assembly**

First of all you need to import that assembly into your database inside SQL Server Management Studio by navigating to the New Assembly dialog window:

> DatabaseName  -> Programmability -> Assemblies -> (Right Click) 'New Assembly...'

Inside the 'New Assembly' dialog window, chose `Browse` under the `Path to assembly` field and select the assembly you want to import. Adjust Permissions and click `ok`.

**Wrap Assembly Methods in a SQL Function**

Next you need to create sql function to wrap your assembly method like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_funcName](@str [varchar](max))
RETURNS 
   varchar(max) 
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [YourSqlAssemblyName].[YourAssemblyName.Class1].[GetName]
```

If you want to return table from your function read about SqlFunctionAttribute in .NET.

Comment: What is the convention for naming your SQL function so that you know which assembly it came from? Or is there a way to check in SQL Server Management Studio the assembly associated with a given procedure?

Comment: @MinhTran As I remember there is no naming convention. You have to keep it in mind. But I'm now sure, that was ages ago.