# Convert VarBinary RTF blob to text in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, binary, blob, rtf

I am using SQL server - 2008.

```
Column Datatype - VarBinary
```

RTF File is  compressed and saved to this varbinary column.

Now how to access and view data in RTF file using SQL ?

it's returns this: `㠰た㠴弰巎楛㵤㠵㜸ㄲ㠴.` etc.

**Sample Tried Code here:**

http://rextester.com/YOFHK34016

any solution to this.
in 2008 Decompress and compress function not work.
how i can get RTF file as it is to text.

Comment: What kind of compression is used?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen compress function Used.  How actullay data in inserted we dont know. if i select top 1 * convert that column to varchar then it restun binary code which placed in query

Answer (score 0):

That's works for me:

```
select convert(varchar(max),convert(varbinary(max),bv.value)) from blobValue bv
```

Instead using nvarchar try to use varchar.
But I shuld say that this will return rtf formated text, something like:

```
"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1251\deff0\deflang1049{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil MS Sans Serif;}{\f1\fswiss\fcharset0 Arial;}"
```

To get actual text from it you can use .Net dll to convert it. 
You can add .net dll to your database and than call it's functions from Sql script. More detailed about it: [Call dll function from sql stored procedure using the current connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916790/call-dll-function-from-sql-stored-procedure-using-the-current-connection)

Comment: qury is not working now. i already used nvarchar and varchar still same error. How i can use .NET DLL ?  can you add more details or demo ?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, thanks a bunch.
I used:

```
SELECT convert(nvarchar(max),convert(varbinary(max),[FORMULATEXT]))
```